# Probability with various stages

Tags: probability

I'm trying to make a probability calculator for a tennis match.

I've already managed to get the probability calculation so I can see what are the chances of winning "the game" for the player who is serving. When "the game" starts, the score is 0-0.

Whoever reaches 4 points first wins "the game". Points 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 correspond to scores 0, 15, 30, 40, and winning "the game". For example, a score of 30-15 would mean that the points are 2-1.

There is of course the possibility that the score goes to "Deuce". This means that we have a score of 40 - 40 or the points are 3 - 3. In order for a player to win the game from a "Deuce", they need to score 2 more points than the other player. For example 5-3 or 6-4 or whatever.

The Boundary conditions:
$$P(a, b) = 1 \quad \text{if} \quad a = 4, b ≤ 2 \\
P(a, b) = 0 \quad \text{if} \quad b = 4, a ≤ 2 \\
P(3, 3) = \frac{p^2}{p^2 + (1 − p)^2}$$

I know that the player who is serving, say Player A, wins 60% of the points when he's serving. This then also means that the other player, say Player B, has 40% chance of winning a point when Player A is serving.
$$G(p) = {p^4 + 4p^4(1 − p) + 10p^4(1 − p)^2} + \frac{20p^5(1 − p)^3}{1 − 2p(1 − p)} \\
= {0.6^4 + 4\cdot 0.6^4\cdot 0.4 + 10\cdot 0.6^4\cdot 0.4^2} + \frac {20\cdot 0.6^5\cdot 0.4^3}{1 - 2\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.4}$$

This gives a probability of 0.736 that Player A reaches 4 points first or in other words, "Winning the game".

So I know that when the game starts Player A has 0.736 chance of getting first to 4 points and that Player be has 0.263 chance of getting first to 4 points.

But what I want to calculate is what if Player A wins the first point. 15 - 0 or 1-0. *What is the probability then that Player A wins the game?*

Comment: if you define 2 events $B$ =  leading 1-0 and $C$ = winning, than you should calculate $P(C/B)$

Comment: @d_e; So something like this: "P(a, b) = p P(a + 1, b) + (1 − p)P(a, b + 1)"?

Comment: $P(C/B) = \dfrac {P(C \cap B) }{P(B)}$. you already have $P(B)$ which is $0.6$.

Comment: @d_e: Sorry but still don't get it. Which values do I have to use than forP(C ∩B)?

Comment: $P(C \cap B)$ = the chance of winning after leading 1-0. I can't follow your calculation in the post. what is the division by 1 - 2p(1-p) ?

Comment: This is to calculate "Deuce". The score can reach 40 - 40 or 3-3. Than the Players need to win 2 more Points to win 'the game"

Comment: @jorli, sorry, forgot to mention that when the score is 40 - 40 or 3-3 than to win the game a Player needs to score 2 more points to win "the game". So it needs to be 5-3 or 6-4 or whatever.